# How to increase the number of test accounts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, ganache, ganache-cli

I have encountered a problem where I need a large number of test accounts.
How can I increase the number of test accounts from 10. Remix and ganache only give 10 accounts. I require more than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Ganache and Ganache CLI

---

With `ganache-cli` you can do this with the `--accounts` flag. For example:

```
ganache-cli --accounts=100
```

Ganache (the desktop application) comes with 100 accounts by default.

#### Remix

---

If you are using the Javascript VM, then you simply need to click the `+` button next to the word "Account"

[image: account add]

If you are using Injected Web3, then whatever is injecting your Web3 (most likely MetaMask) needs to have all those accounts. You must create more accounts there.

Finally, if you are using a Web3 provider, you must make sure that the provider you are pointing it to (probably ganache) has the accounts available. In order to do this, follow the "Ganache and Ganache CLI" section above.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add into Shane's answer, if you are testing with `ganache-cli`,
you can also do this:

```
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 =  require('web3');
const options = { a: 100 }; // NO OF ACCOUNTS
const provider = ganache.provider(options);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

I hope that helps.