# How to use truffle HDWalletProvider to get more then 10 addresses with funds for test purpose

Tags: truffle, ganache, ganache-cli, truffle-hdwallet-provider, hdwalletprovider

How do I need to call HDWalletProvider to get for example 50 addresses with funds?

The networks part in my `truffle.js` configuration file looks like this:

```
networks: {
    development: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "http://127.0.0.1:8545/", 0, 50);
      },
      network_id: '*'
    }
  }
```

With this, I have 50 addresses but it looks like only the first 10 have funds.

I am trying this with the following versions:
Ganache CLI v6.12.2 (ganache-core: 2.13.2)
Truffle v5.3.2 - a development framework for Ethereum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/70828/70381):

Just start the `ganache-cli` with the extra argument `--accounts=<number of accounts>`

E.g.: `ganache-cli --accounts=100`